# Format input URL to save domain and tld

Tags: bash

I'm working on a bash script but currently stuck because I need a function that should be invoked this way:

`check_domain url`

```
function check_domain() {
... 
}
```

Having an URL as input, that can be for example: (or any other possibility).

- http://domain.tld
- https://domain.tld
- http://www.domain.tld
- https://www.domain.tld
- [www.domain.tld](http://www.domain.tld)
- domain.tld

I would need to save just "domain.tld" into a variable.

For example, for "https://stackoverflow.com" or "http://www.stackoverflow.com",the variable should be "stackoverflow.com" in both cases.

How could I do?

I appreciate your help!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself. Please take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What should be the output in this cases? `https://www.example.co.uk` and `https://ftp.example.co.uk`

Comment: Hello @Cyrus thats a good one :) In such cases should be ```example.co.uk```, also if there is any slash after tld like www.example.co.uk/index. Thank you so much!

Comment: I assume that you have to integrate a [long list](https://publicsuffix.org/list/effective_tld_names.dat) into your function in order to be able to distinguish the cases.